# Why does my event handler only work in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out why my simple javascript application will work fine in chrome, but not in firefox or internet explorer (note: I'm just a student, so please bear with me, and thanks!).

In firefox and internet explorer, I can browse and select a text file, but once selected it does nothing, which is why I'm assuming the event handler is the problem. I can't seem to find anything about there being differences in the way browser handle the onchange event.

To be thorough and concise at the same time, I'll add the entire web application but I think the only relevant portion is the event handler in main.js. I'm pretty sure the problem is with that, but I'm not 100% sure.

EDIT: Internet Explorer works now. The problem was that scripts were being blocked since it was a local file. Still doesn't work in Firefox, and I don't see anything about scripts being blocked. It shouldn't be any plugins either because I only have 3: Lastpass, Chatzilla, and Freemake Video Downloader.

In Chrome (How it's supposed to work):
[image]

In Firefox (Not working):
[image]

Firefox javascript console:
[image]

HTML (frontend.html):

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<div>
  Select a text file: 
  <input type="file" id="fileInput">
</div>
<pre id="fileDisplayArea"></pre>
```

Javascript (main.js)

```
window.onload = function() {

// Initialize associative array to store contents of the tic tac toe board.

var board = {
northwest_square: "", north_square: "", northeast_square: "",
west_square: "", center_square: "", east_square: "",
southwest_square: "", south_square: "", southeast_square: ""
};

// Read the file and store into string variable "fileStr"
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var textType = /text.*/;

  if (file.type.match(textType)) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var fileStr = reader.result.toLowerCase();

    //remove whitespace
    fileStr=fileStr.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

    //Store into the array
    var i = 0;
    for(var index in board){
      board[index] = fileStr[i];
      i++;
    }

    var winner = findWinner();

    //Display board
    fileDisplayArea.innerText += reader.result.toLowerCase();

    //Display winner
    switch(winner){
        case "INVALID":
            fileDisplayArea.innerText += "\n\nINVALID: File contents     must be 'x', 'o', or '_'";
            break;
        case "INCOMPLETE":
            fileDisplayArea.innerText += "\n\nINCOMPLETE: No winner found. Unused blocks exist.";
            break;
        case "TIE": 
            fileDisplayArea.innerText += "\n\nTIE: No winners found."
            break;
    }
    if(winner != 'INVALID' && winner != "INCOMPLETE" && winner != "TIE"){
      fileDisplayArea.innerText += "\n\nCongratulations player '" + winner + "'. You are the winner!";
    }

  }

  reader.readAsText(file);  
  } else {
    fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!";
  }
});

//FUNCTION(S)
function findWinner(){
//check if contents are 'x', 'o' or '_';
for(var index in board){
    if(board[index] != 'x' 
        && board[index] != 'o' 
        && board[index] != '_'){
        return "INVALID";
    }
}
        // ROW1 (NW, N, NE)
        if(board["northwest_square"] === board["north_square"]
            && board["northeast_square"] === board["north_square"]
            && board["north_square"] != '_'){

            // If triple, then return contents (either 'x' or 'o')
            return board["north_square"];
        }
        // ROW2 (W, Center, E)
        else if(board["west_square"] === board["center_square"]
            && board["east_square"] === board["center_square"]
            && board["center_square"] != '_'){

            // If triple, then return contents (either 'x' or 'o')
            return board["center_square"];
        }
        // ROW3 (SW, S, SE)
        else if(board["southwest_square"] === board["south_square"]
            && board["southeast_square"] === board["south_square"]
            && board["south_square"] != '_'){

            // If triple, then return contents (either 'x' or 'o')
            return board["south_square"];
        }
        // COL1 (NW, W, SW)
        else if(board["northwest_square"] === board["west_square"]
            && board["southwest_square"] === board["west_square"]
            && board["west_square"] != '_'){

            // If triple, then return contents (either 'x' or 'o')
            return board["west_square"];
        }
        // COL2 (N, Center, S)
        else if(board["north_square"] === board["center_square"]
            && board["south_square"] === board["center_square"]
            && board["center_square"] != '_'){

            // If triple, then return contents (either 'x' or 'o')
            return board["center_square"];
        }
        // COL3 (NE, E, SE)
        else if(board["northeast_square"] === board["east_square"]
            && board["southeast_square"] === board["east_square"]
            && board["east_square"] != '_'){

            // If triple, then return contents (either 'x' or 'o')
            return board["east_square"];
        }
        // DIAG1 (NW, Center, SE) 
        else if(board["northwest_square"] === board["center_square"]
            && board["southeast_square"] === board["center_square"]
            && board["center_square"] != '_'){

            // If triple, then return contents (either 'x' or 'o')
            return board["center_square"];
        }
        // DIAG2 (NE, Center, SW)
        else if(board["northeast_square"] === board["center_square"]
            && board["southwest_square"] === board["center_square"]
            && board["center_square"] != '_'){

            // If triple, then return contents (either 'x' or 'o')
            return board["center_square"];
        }
        else if(board["northwest_square"] === '_' 
            || board["north_square"] === '_'
            || board["northeast_square"] === '_'
            || board["west_square"] === '_'
            || board["center_square"] === '_'
            || board["east_square"] === '_'
            || board["southeast_square"] === '_'
            || board["south_square"] === '_'
            || board["southwest_square"] === '_'){
            return "INCOMPLETE";
        }
        else{
            return "TIE";
        }
}
```

}

Text file (tictactoe.txt):

```
oxo
oox
xox
```

Comment: Are there errors in the other browsers?  Is the `change` event being called at all?

Comment: Try registering `reader.onerror` and see if anything is being fired?

Comment: Will look into both right now, one sec.

Comment: @SuperScript - Added Javascript console output in Firefox, but I didn't see anything that would help. Probably doesn't answer your question. How would I figure out if it's being called for sure? And no nothing shows up in the consoles of the other browsers.

Comment: OK, I found out that in internet explorer there was a box that said ActiveX controls were blocked. When I enabled them it started to work. Firefox is still having problems.

Comment: Ok registered reader.onerror and didn't get anything:reader.onerror = function (stuff) {
  console.log("error", stuff)
  console.log(stuff.getMessage())
  }

Answer (score 0):

I had solution, but it was drag & drop. What are your IE version needs? Only IE 10+ supports it.

Comment: It's just a side project I'm using to learn, so I'm not really looking for a different solution that works, unless I understand my current problem and why that solution is better. Thank you though!